# Is a raspberry Pi suitable for running as a music bot on discord?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, headless, media-server

Excuse my etiquette in advance if I make a mistake from the rules this is my first time on StackExchange.

My Raspberry Pi is a little outdated a Pi 2B but it does tasks it is asked. My main question is, would my Raspberry Pi be safe running 24/7 as a Headless Discord music bot with some heavy usage around night and little to none in the morning until noon? I don't have any fans on it but heat syncs, yes.

And an additional question would it be smart to have a jump drive hooked up to the Pi so the SD card is only being used by the operating system and the Jump Drive is where the audio files and cache is stored?

Comment: The short answer is yes and yes, but why not just try it.

Comment: I did this for a long time with my Pi2 (although it was more than just music specific). No heat sinks or anything. To be honest, near the end, I ignored it as I moved onto projects with my Pi3s, so the Pi2 eventually was found covered in my step-daughter's rabbit's fur, and still ticked along. You shouldn't see problems. Just take better care of the Pi than I did.

Comment: Thank you @stevieb good to know, did you ever use a Flash Drive as a storage unit?

And SteveRobillard Thank you for your input, I'll try it out.